# ScrollView to auto-resize its height according to content in a UIView?

Tags: iphone, xcode, uiscrollview

I need to auto-resize the height of a UIScrollView.Actually my ScrollView is in a UIView.
In the UIView I have a label,UIButton, textField of static size.Now when the button is clicked some data gets loaded in the UITableView.The data in tableView is dynamic according to the no of objects in the array.

To summarize :
On viewLoad only label,textField,button gets loaded.
After buttonClick tableView gets loaded .

So I need to adjust the height of scrollView according to this criteria.But unable to do..

```
-(IBAction)buttonClick
{

                [testscroll setScrollEnabled:YES];
                [testscroll setContentSize:CGSizeMake(320,90+[array count]*180)];
                [self.view addSubview:testscroll];
  self.tableView=[[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,150,327,[array count]*180) style:UITableViewStylePlain];
                self.tableView.delegate=self;
                self.tableView.dataSource=self;
                self.tableView.rowHeight=180;
                self.tableView.scrollEnabled = NO;
                [self.view addSubview:self.tableView];
                [tableView release];

}
```

I couldn't c d scrollView added on button click..How can I get it ?

Comment: it seems you are already setting the content size of the scroll view, so what is exactly your problem. What does not work with the code above? what is the content of the scroll view? does it scroll?

Comment: what i need is on button click I need to auto-resize height of ScrollView.But the ScrollView doesn't get added nd im unable to scroll

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this bellow code..

```
   self.tableView.frame=CGRectMake(self.tableView.frame.origin.x, 150, self.tableView.frame.size.width, self.tableView.frame.size.height); /// you can set self.tableView.contentSize.height for set dynamic height of table with data ..

    float fscrview = self.tableView.frame.origin.y + self.tableView.frame.size.height + 20;
    yourScrollView.contentSize=CGSizeMake(320, fscrview);
```